# examples of semi structured data ?

Tags: data

i read that Json or XML are unstructured data; Are Json or XML data or are they tools to tag the data?

I understand from this wikipedia page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-structured_data) that semi structured data are data without a formal database structure, but still have some tags;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON and XML are not tools. They are data formats. For example, to find out more about JSON you can look up the RFC description that specifies how to format JSON files:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159

It explains how to tag the data. Then there are tools that validate JSON, and XML files to see if they conform to the requirements, or there are tools that convert JSON into another format or read it into memory into some object or class.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the site!

[JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) and [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) are file formats used for representing textual data, thus they are a standard way of representing it. As they are very generic, there are many further more precise formats that build on these to specify particular uses. Since XML has been around for longer, it is easy to think of examples for it. Consider HTML (in fact HTML is looser than XML, so a more correct example would be XHTML, which is the variant of HTML that is strictly compliant with XML) and [OpenDocument Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument) as examples of file formats that build on XML.

Whereas XML was always intended for document-like structures, JSON actually represents a tree in which each node is a key-value pair. A branch in the tree is one where the value is another tree (or if you like another JSON). While one might not find this to be so much different from XML, it is the original intention of the creators of the formats that slightly differs.

XML and JSON are considered file formats that represent semi-structured data, because both of them represent data in a hierarchical ([tree-like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_structure)) structure. For an example of tree-like structure, consider [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model), which represents the hierarchical structure and while commonly used for HTML. It can also be attributed more generally to any XML and JSON document.

There could be some debate whether tree-like structures are used to represent unstructured or semi-structured data. These trees could also be called [documents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-oriented_database) in the context of databases, where [Relational databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database) (i.e. SQL) are considered structured. The reason why they are rather commonly considered unstructured is that the tree-like structure is very loose restriction, and in fact through *id references* (id-ref) other, atypical for trees substructures (like loops or shortcuts) are also possible. Furthermore XML and JSON specify this general structure, but do not specify what labels or substructures it contains. Thus, they are more commonly considered as unstructured.

Answer (score 0):

[Json](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) and [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) are file-formats/file-types typically used for sharing information from and to the website or the webpage. JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation while XML stands for eXtended Markup Language.

Typically in data science, semi structured datasets are required to be shared, for which such file types comes very handy. The choice of sharing the semi-structured datasets largely depends on the user and these formats are used as they are easy to interface with web-frameworks too.

Data could be stored into these file formats and can be parsed to a dictionary or a DataFrame. Structured data in the form of DataFrames is easy to process and use.